# Comments for microposts in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

After successfully completeling a micropost system. Logged in users can post through the form and create a post. I begun to add to this but allowing any user to comment on a post as well.

I get a multitude of errors. And for the most part I don't know what the problem is so would like some advise on how to get this finished. Right now the error is:

NameError in StaticPages#home
undefined local variable or method `micropost'

StaticPages#home is the page that displays everyones microposts, and thus the comments form as well. users#show is the public profile of users and displays the same as statispages (have yet to work out how to make posts to a users wall, eventually main page will be a general feed and user page will be a user-to-user feed).

Comments model

```
  create_table "comments", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "content"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.integer  "micropost_id"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end
```

User.rb

```
  class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :microposts, dependent: :destroy
    has_many :comments
```

micropost.rb

```
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy
```

comment.rb

```
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :micropost
```

comments_controller.rb

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :signed_in_user, only: [:create, :destroy]

  def create
    @micropost = Micropost.find(params[:micropost_id])
    @comment = Comment.new(params[:comment])
    @comment.micropost = @micropost
    @comment.user = current_user
    if @comment.save
       flash[:success] = "Comment created!"
       redirect_to current_user
    else
      render 'shared/_comment_form'
    end
  end
end
```

microposts_controller.rb

```
class MicropostsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!
  before_action :correct_user,   only: :destroy

  def index
    @microposts = Micropost.all
    @comment = @micropost.comments.build(params[:comment])
    @comment.user = current_user
  end

  def create
    @micropost = current_user.microposts.build(micropost_params)
    if @micropost.save
      flash[:success] = "Micropost created!"
      redirect_to root_url
    else
      @feed_items = []
      render root_url
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @micropost.destroy
    redirect_to root_url
  end

  private

    def micropost_params
      params.require(:micropost).permit(:content)
    end

    def correct_user
      @micropost = current_user.microposts.find_by(id: params[:id])
      redirect_to root_url if @micropost.nil?
    end
end
```

users_controller.rb

```
  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @microposts = @user.microposts
    @comment = Comment.new
    if user_signed_in?
      @micropost  = current_user.microposts.build
      @feed_items = current_user.feed
    end
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.xml  { render :xml => @user }
    end
  end
```

Anyplace calling the comment form

```
<%= render 'shared/comment_form', micropost: micropost %>
```

_comment_form.html.erb

```
<%= form_for([micropost, @comment]) do |f| %> #Here's the current error#
<%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.text_area :content, :placeholder => "Leave a comment" %>
  </div>
  <button class="btn" type="submit">
    Create
  </button>
<% end %>
```

Schema shows all the correct fields of the model. All DB migrations have been done. I've seen it say that in form_for([micropost, @comment]) the first field cannot be nil. I'm assuming this means that the comments aren't correctly filling micropost_id with the id of the micropost they attach to.

Comment: I cannot really help you with the error, but I can offer a suggestion to help you debug - try the gem [better_errors](https://github.com/charliesome/better_errors) - this gives an interactive shell at the point of failure, with a full stack trace, etc. You could use it to find out if or why `micropost` is nil, for instance.

Comment: change this <%= render 'shared/comment_form', micropost: micropost %> to <%= render 'shared/comment_form', locals: { micropost: micropost } %> and see if it works, not sure...

Comment: another resource for debugging is here: http://nofail.de/2013/10/debugging-rails-applications-in-development/

Comment: I tried your suggestion Rahul, better_errors shows the error to be on this line
<%= form_for([micropost, @comment]) do |f| %>

Comment: Can you provide the code of the view and controller StaticPages#home?

Comment: Home view just calls the micropost form (which in turn calls the comment form)
`<%= render 'shared/micropost_form' %>`
and controller:
  
`def home
    if user_signed_in?
      @micropost  = current_user.microposts.build
      @feed_items = current_user.feed
    end
  end`